# Android BLE - Read data of characteristic - How to add characteristic for the button

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have a class DiviceControlActivity. Inside of class is list of UUID service and characteristic. When Click on UUID characteristic the data is read about characteristic and is shown.

But I want to replace the list by Button. When I click on Button it should read the characteristic and show it.I have a problem with my code: Please help me.

This is code about list of UUID:

```
private final ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener servicesListClickListner = new  ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {       
   @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        if (mGattCharacteristics != null) {
            final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = mGattCharacteristics
                    .get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
            final int charaProp = characteristic.getProperties();
            if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) > 0) {
                // If there is an active notification on a characteristic,
                // clear
                // it first so it doesn't update the data field on the user
                // interface.
                if (mNotifyCharacteristic != null) {
                    mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                            mNotifyCharacteristic, false);
                    mNotifyCharacteristic = null;
                }
                mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
            }
            if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) > 0) {
                mNotifyCharacteristic = characteristic;
                mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                        characteristic, true);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

And this is code of the button:

```
mBattery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = mGattCharacteristics
                    .get(4).get(1);
            displayData(characteristic.getService().toString());
            mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
        }
    });
```

Problem is when I click the Button: "BLE has stopped".
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should check logcat so you can see the stacktrace from the Exception that you're getting. Without knowing if you have checks in place in other parts of your code, you could easily be getting a `NullPointerException` or an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, especially since you're hardcoding the array indices in `mBattery.setOnClickListener` (i.e. 4 and 1).

More generally, the way you're registering for notifications won't work and may be causing issues. Here's a sample of how to do it:

```
if( mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(mNotifyCharacteristic, true) )
{
    final UUID CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIGURATION_DESCRIPTOR_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

    BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = mNotifyCharacteristic.getDescriptor(CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIGURATION_DESCRIPTOR_UUID);

    if( descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE) )
    {
        if( mBluetoothLeService.writeDescriptor(descriptor) )
        {
            // Now wait for callback to BluetoothGattCallback#onDescriptorWrite().
        }
    }
}
```